# Generating a random density matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, random, physics, operators

I am interested in using Mathematica to generate random $N\times N$ density matrices describing pure quantum states; for the less physics-oriented folks, a density matrix is positive semi-definite, self-adjoint, has trace $1$ and describes a pure state if it is also idempotent.

Does anyone know of a quick implementation?

Comment: Mathematica has a number of built-in matrix distributions which could maybe be used as building blocks to create what you are looking for: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixDistributions.html

Comment: You can get matrices with the positive-semi-definite property, the trace-1 property, and the self-adjoint (Hermitian?) property like this using a simple covariance matrix `cv = #/Tr[#] &@Covariance[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}]]; PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[cv] && HermitianMatrixQ[cv]` . It should also work with `RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {5, 5}]` too. However I'm not sure about the idempotent property - that probably takes more careful construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to start with a random pure state and then form a density matrix in that state:

```
randomPureState[n_] := RandomComplex[{-1-I, 1+I}, n] // Normalize
singleStateDensityMatrix[state_] := Outer[Times, state, Conjugate[state]]

randomPureDensityMatrix[n_] := singleStateDensityMatrix @ randomPureState @ n
```

We can also define a test for validity:

```
test[m_] :=
  <| "Hermitian" -> HermitianMatrixQ[m]
   , "PosSemiDef" -> PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m]
   , "Trace1" -> Tr[m]==1
   , "Idempotent" -> AllTrue[Chop[m.m-m], # == 0 &, 2]
   |> // <| #, "Valid" -> And@@# |> &
```

So then:

```
SeedRandom[1]
$m = randomPureDensityMatrix[4]
$m // MatrixForm
```

[image: random pure density matrix]

```
test[$m]
(*
<|"Hermitian"->True,"PosSemiDef"->True,"Trace1"->True,"Idempotent"->True,"Valid"->True|>
*)
```

```
AllTrue[Table[randomPureDensityMatrix[4], 100000], test[#]["Valid"] &]
(* True *)
```

**Caveats**

The present definition of `randomPureState` neglects the extremely tiny possibility of generating an invalid null state.  It is left to the reader to add that check if desired.

Also, `randomPureState` is simplistic and does not generate states uniformly across the state space.  If uniformity is desired, then one should use more elaborate methods.  See, for example, [Generating and using truly random quantum states in Mathematica](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4598.pdf) (Miszczak 2011).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to generate matrices that satisfy all the properties you want:

```
randomDensityMatrix[n_] := Module[{m, m2,
    (* You could also use RandomComplex here instead *)
    W = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}],
    (* matrix with a single 1 on the diagonal and zero elsewhere *)
    V = SparseArray[({#, #} -> 1) &@RandomInteger[{1, n}], {n, n}]
  },
  m = Inverse[W].V.W;
  (* force the trace to be 1 *)
  m2 = #/Tr[#] &@(m.Transpose[m]);
  (* check it satisfies all desired properties *)
  Assert[m2.m2 == m2 && HermitianMatrixQ[m2] && 
    PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m2] && Tr[m2] == 1];
  Return[m2];
]
```

Comment: Use On[Assert] if you want the assertion to check it. If I replace `V` with a diagonal matrix with any number of 1s i.e `DiagonalMatrix@RandomInteger[1,n]` then it may not always satisfy the idempotent property `m2.m2 == m2`, but I'm pretty sure a single 1 guarantees this and you can check loads of them with `On[Assert]; Do[randomDensityMatrix[5], {i, 1000}]; Off[Assert]`